# Webcam not being detected

Tags: windows-10, webcam

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 5000 series laptop which is running Windows 10.

Starting a few days ago, the built-in webcam that comes with the laptop stopped working completely. Programs like Skype, TestWebCam, and others fail to detect the webcam.

[image: Error Code 0xA00F4246]

I have tried all the steps from [Dell's official troubleshooting guide](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN85507/dell-webcam-and-dell-webcam-central-software-guide?lang=EN):

1. Updating drivers for the Integrated Webcam in Device Manager gave the
   message "The best drivers for your device are already installed."
2. Uninstalling the drivers for the Integrated Webcam.
3. Updating to the latest BIOS A12 had no effect.
4. Updating to the latest Chipset 16.400.3601 also had no effect.
5. [Dell's PC Diagnostics](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN298246/how-to-use-the-dell-pc-diagnostics?lang=EN) more than 1 hour scan didn't find any webcam related issues.
6. [Access to the camera is enabled in Windows 10's privacy settings](https://www.earthslab.com/computer-science/windows-10-webcam-error-code-0xa00f4246/).

Comment: Your webcam (or its connecter) is broken.

Comment: It was working fine, till last week, and no sort of physical damage occurred during this time. How can it get broken on its own?

Comment: You have done everything possible as regarding software, so hardware is indicated.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the very first version of webcam driver.
2. Switch off the network (go offline).
3. Uninstall webcam driver
4. Install that very first driver.
5. check the performance.

If it is still the same, it probably is a hardware issue.

Comment: It worked thank you so much! Idk how but it worked perfectly fine with the old webcam drivers. Thank you!